# Javascript string replace '&zwj' is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a dropdown by using html's select tag.
And I needed to add a space bar `&emsp` before the label in option like this:

```
<div class="item" data-value="0399">&emsp;Fruits </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&emsp;&emsp;Banana </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&emsp;&emsp;Apple </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&emsp;&emsp;Kiwi </div>
```

This works well in desktop mode, but not on my iphone.
My iphone's Chrome browser did not render the `&emsp`.

So, I resolved this problem by adding `&zwj;` before `&emsp;` like this:

```
<div class="item" data-value="0399">&zwj;&emsp;Fruits </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Banana </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Apple </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Kiwi </div>
```

But, I found that I can not remove the '‍ ' by using javascript.
This is what I have tried:

```
text.replace(/&zwj;&emsp;/g, ''))
text.replace(/&zwj;|&emsp;/g, ''))
text.replace(/&emsp;/g, ''))
```

Would you please suggest how I can remove that '‍ ' from the text?

--- edited for more specification.

```
<div class="item" data-value="0399">&zwj;&emsp;Fruits </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Banana And Apple </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Apple And Kiwi </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Kiwi And pineapple </div>
```

How to delete `&zwj;` and `&emsp;` in that node?

---- edit

this code works well.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  .forEach((item) => {
  item.textContent = item.textContent.match(/[\w ]+/);
});
```

But,

```
<div class="item" data-value="0399">&zwj;&emsp;과일</div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;화학 공업 양론 </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;그렁 그렁 열매</div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;불라 불라</div>
```

in this case, that code not works well.(that is korean)

check this please.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  .forEach((item) => {
    item.textContent = item.textContent.match(/[\w ]+/);
});
```

```html
<div class="item" data-value="0399">&zwj;&emsp;과일</div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;화학 공업 양론 </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;그렁 그렁 열매</div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;불라 불라</div>
```

Comment: Those nodes don't contain the value `'&zwj;'` they contain a zero-width joiner character (U+200D). So when you attempt to write a regular expression, you'll need to match that character.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks, then how to do that? text.match('&zwj') like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match by `[\S]` this will match any character but a whitespace so we could use it opposite way like this `[^\S]`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  .forEach((item) => {
    item.textContent = item.textContent.replace(/[^\S]+/g," ");
  });
```

```html
<div class="item" data-value="0399">&zwj;&emsp;과일</div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;화학 공업 양론 </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;그렁 그렁 열매</div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;불라 불라</div>
```

Comment: wow, thank you! , but, how can I keep other space bar ? like this `화학 공업 양론` not `화학공업양론`

Comment: @ByeonginYoon ok just like this replace(/[^\S]+/g," ");

Comment: @ByeonginYoon test it now

Comment: Yes, Thank you! but, there is a spacebar in front of `화학 공업 양론`

Answer (score 0):

Identify the words inside, and set the `textContent` to the word found:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  .forEach((item) => {
    item.textContent = item.textContent.match(/[\w ]+/);
  });
```

```html
<div class="item" data-value="0399">&zwj;&emsp;Fruits </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Banana And Apple </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Apple And Kiwi </div>
<div class="item" data-value="0359">&zwj;&emsp;&zwj;&emsp;Kiwi And pineapple </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to delete &zwj;&emsp; not only &emsp

Comment: Oh, I see. Edited - just match the words instead of trying to remove the spaces.

Comment: Thanks but, in my case that code return null. My text was `&zwj;&emsp;단위결합 및 공중분해` This is korean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it in unicode in your regex.

That is `u200D` and `u2003`.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: How to use that in javascript? I'm really newbie on Regex.